# Swift 2.0 : Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to force unwrap but, it doesn't work. I have also tried a different variant of unwrapping which uses, "let", but I am unable to unwrap it using print.

[image]

Note that, the linked answers did not work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can show the error with an image but you also have to transcript the error in text

Comment: just curious, what does transcript the error in text mean? couldn't quiet get it.

Comment: You have to write in text behind the image, the error text (in this case: "Cannot subscript..."). Imagine the image doesn't load for someone, he'd like to understand the error anyway.

Comment: why a down vote? come on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an array, to create a dictionary you have to change `var dict = ["name: josh", "age: 40", "gender: male"]` with `var dict = ["name": "josh", "age": "40", "gender": "male"]`

Comment: I changed the dictionary, but it still doesn't print(dict["name"]!) in the playground.

Comment: Sorry. Works as a charm. :)